# Changing / adding files to a git tag?

Tags: git, bash, tags

I'm just familiarizing myself with git and now, git tags.  Based on what I've understood to date, tags are just a snapshot of a point in time in history that we want to track.  For example, for version numbers.

I have a client who wants me to add / backport a bug fix to version 1.0 when we are now on version 2.0.  The idea being that when we image a new v1.0 box, the bug fix is included.

I'm not sure how I would do this.

I have the following tags in the repo:

```
v2.0
v1.0
v0.1
```

I've tried to check out the tagged version by running the command

```
git checkout v1.0
```

Then I made my bug fix changes. 
And then I tried:

```
git add .
git commit
git push
```

When I do the push, I get an error message stating that the updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote counterpart.
I'm currently googling this error but I would like to know if fundamentally, I'm doing something that I shouldn't.

Comment: This is possible somehow I guess, but it doesn't make sense. Push new versions that fix bugs in old versions. That's how the concept works.

Comment: *[...] add / backport a bug fix to version 1.0 when we are now on version 2.0.* That would involve rewriting the history of your repo from v1.0 onwards, which is not a simple operation. Are you sure that's what you want to do?

Comment: @IonicăBizău, thanks. That's what i wanted to discuss.  From reading, i don't get the impression that tags are meant to be changed. So if I create the bug fix and check into master... how does someone starting with v1.0 know that this patch / bug fix needs to be applied too?  How do you "flag" the patch as being applicable to v1.0 and v2.0?

Comment: @dot You're talking about maintaining two versions in parallel? If so, you can create v0.1.x, where `x` takes values from `0` to what you want. But, the differences between versions are noted in `CHANGELOG`. That's where you say: *Bug `x` was fixed.*.

Comment: @IonicăBizău ok sounds good.  that's what I will do.  thanks.

Comment: @dot I tried to post a good answer. +1, probably this will be helpful for other people

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Overriding a tag/version is a bad practice in general. Since you only want to fix a bug from an older version, they way `git` works is to create a new tag with that bug fixed.

That's why we have [CHANGELOG thing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Changelog) -- it helps humans to view the differences between versions/releases.

In the case of fixing a bug in an older version (`v0.1.0`) while a new version (`v0.2.0`) has log of changes and cannot be synced with the old one, you probably want to create a new tag like `v0.1.1`:

```
# creating v0.1.0
git init
echo "console.log('Hello Wrold')" > main.js
git add .
git commit -m 'Initial commit'
git tag v0.1.0
git remote add origin ...
git push --all
git push --tags
# creating v0.2.0
echo "console.log('Hello Mars')" > main.js
git commit -m 'Hello Mars instead of Hello world' .
git tag v0.2.0
git push --all
git push --tags
# fixing typo from v0.1.0 (edit/add files) and creating v0.1.1
git checkout v0.1.0
echo "console.log('Hello World')" > main.js
git commit -m 'Fixed typo.' .
git tag v0.1.1
git push --tags
# go back to main branch
git checkout master
```

`Fixed typo.` commit will not appear in `master` branch since it was added only in `v0.1.1` tag.

---

So, what if I want to override `v0.1.0`? If that's a bad practice, doesn't make it impossible. Instead of creating a new version (`git tag v0.1.1`) we can delete the old `v0.1.0` and create it again, forcing pushing on remote:

```
... # fixed typo
git tag -d v0.1.0
git tag v0.1.0
git push --tags -f
# go back to main branch
git checkout master
```

---

On GitHub, it releases will be listed like this:

> [image]

Let's see the differences:

```
$ git diff v0.1.0 v0.2.0 
diff --git a/main.js b/main.js
index 07e8cb2..7b366c5 100644
--- a/main.js
+++ b/main.js
@@ -1 +1 @@
-console.log('Hello Wrold')
+console.log('Hello Mars')
$ git diff v0.1.1 v0.2.0
diff --git a/main.js b/main.js
index ba72797..7b366c5 100644
--- a/main.js
+++ b/main.js
@@ -1 +1 @@
-console.log('Hello World')
+console.log('Hello Mars')
$ git diff v0.1.0 v0.1.1
diff --git a/main.js b/main.js
index 07e8cb2..ba72797 100644
--- a/main.js
+++ b/main.js
@@ -1 +1 @@
-console.log('Hello Wrold')
+console.log('Hello World')
```

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing `tags` with `commits`.  Usually `tags` are analogous to `pointers to commits`.

For your scenario a typical model would be as follow

```
# Create a release branch for v1 
git checkout -b v1_release v1.0
# make your bug fixes, `git commit`, etc.
emacs foo
git add foo
git commit -m "critical bug fix"
# tag your new release 
git tag v1.1
# push the branch and the tags to the server 
git push ...
```

To see what versions have the fix you would use `git branch --contains FIX_SHA` or `git tag --contains FIX_SHA`

You could also create a v2_release branch and `git merge` the fix there.

I would never recommend reusing the same version number for two different code images that were flashed onto hardware.  That sounds like a customer relations and support nightmare.